# TSQL - Query a list of dates between two date fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Data:

```
DECLARE @Dates TABLE
    (
        [MyDate]  DATE
      , [WkStart] DATE
      , [WkEnd]   DATE
    ) ;

INSERT INTO @Dates
SELECT  '2021-10-03'
      , '2021-09-27'
      , '2021-10-03'
UNION
SELECT  '2021-10-21'
      , '2021-10-18'
      , '2021-10-24'
UNION ALL
SELECT  '2021-10-23'
      , '2021-10-18'
      , '2021-10-24'
UNION
SELECT  '2021-10-27'
      , '2021-10-25'
      , '2021-10-31' ;
```

Goal:

To output 2 fields. 1st = a date field and 2nd = a bit field. Date field will have all the dates between [WkStart] and [WkEnd] for each record. Bit field will be true when [MyDate] equals the value of the first field. The table is quite large and so performance matters a lot. When 2+ [MyDate] values belong to the same week range, the Dates for the week should not repeat.

Expected output:

[image]

My try:

```
; WITH recrCTE AS
    (
        SELECT  CAST ( [WkStart] AS DATETIME ) AS [DateVal]
              , [WkEnd]
              , [MyDate]
        FROM    @Dates
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  [DateVal] + 1
              , [WkEnd]
              , [MyDate]
        FROM    recrCTE
        WHERE   [DateVal] + 1 <= [WkEnd]
    )
SELECT  [DateVal]
      , IIF ( [MyDate] = [DateVal], 1, 0 ) AS [isMyDate]
FROM    recrCTE
ORDER BY [DateVal]
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 ) ;
```

Current output:

[image]

Two obvious issues with this solution. 1st, records repeat for 2+ dates that fall within same date range (21st Oct and 23rd Oct). 2nd, both of those dates repeat with 2 different bit values so can't simply use DISTINCT. 3rd that I feel might become an issue is performance. Maybe there's a more efficient way to achieve this (using a function perhaps) instead of using a recursive CTE.

Comment: for your `1st` and `2nd` issue, a quick way is do a `GROUP BY DateVal`, `MAX(isMyDate)`. For performance, use a tally table instead of recursive cte

Comment: The most rows you can have _in a week_ would be 7, right? And you say the table is large, do you need to run the query against _the whole table every time_ or are you going to have reasonable predicates for smaller date ranges than _all of time_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need recursion when there can only be 7 days in a week; just hard-code the 7 values 1-7 so you can use those to explode the set from `WkStart` to 6 days later. Then you can conditionally aggregate that output on `DateVal`.

```
;WITH alldays AS 
(
  SELECT DateVal = DATEADD(DAY, days.n-1, d.WkStart), 
         d.MyDate
  FROM @Dates AS d
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) AS days(n)
  -- if the table is large and performance is a concern, then:
  -- WHERE d.? -- some reasonable where clause belongs here?
)
SELECT DateVal, 
       IsMyDate = MAX(CASE MyDate WHEN DateVal THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM alldays 
GROUP BY DateVal
ORDER BY DateVal;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=698a6c950406ae4b8a3455c66e7c939e)

Comment: Thanks Aaron! By "large table," I meant this query will be part of a report procedure that can span over multiple years so @Dates can get large (still less than 1K records). In any case, this is a great solution. Thank you!! I started playing around with tally table sort of query (double CTE's) after reading squirrel's suggestion (Thank you as well) and although exec plan shows equal cost, your exec plan is MUCH CLEANER. Makes sense to simply cross join to 1-7 values. Thanks again! Hope to see you again at one of the SQL Saturdays in future. Cheers!

Comment: @007 no problem James Bond!

Comment: Why don;t you just do 0 to 6, then you don't need `-1`

Comment: @Charlieface Because I've found that people then question "why did you use 0-based because people don't think about days of the week as 0-6." I can't win, especially when you're around.

Comment: Considering [how much I drove Itzik nuts](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) with tally functions, agreed, you can't :-) We made specific optimizations there to avoid an extra subtraction. I guess this is the difference between thinking as a coder vs thinking as a normal person: number start at 0.

Comment: @Charlieface well, most of the people coming here for help are not 0-based thinkers, in my experience.

Comment: An OOP developer entered the chat.. haha Great suggestion Charlie. And I completely fit Aaron's "typical SQL OP on SO." :) p.s. Y'all go watch my movie in a theater near you.

Comment: @007 I saw it at a drive-in this weekend, it was very good.